# Apache Tomcat Threads in WAITING state while thread pool increases Class name is ImageLoadWorker

Tags: java, tomcat, sap-commerce-cloud

I got this type thread dump on tomcat, All thread are in wating state.
So application is slow down.
Please suggest me the solution for that.
I am using Tomcat 7 and java 7

```
"ImageLoadWorker(653)" prio=5 tid=0x2089 nid=0x829 in Object.wait() - stats: cpu=0 blk=-1 wait=-1
 java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on org.xhtmlrenderer.swing.ImageLoadQueue@4651e7d2
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.swing.ImageLoadQueue.getTask(ImageLoadQueue.java:83)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.swing.ImageLoadWorker.run(ImageLoadWorker.java:53)
    Locked synchronizers: count = 0
```

Comment: You don't think that maybe knowing your code might help?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Actually we implement Lazy loading for image load for search result on browser using "JQuery unveil" library for that, So that time this type of thread dump will be created

Comment: @V.P,then this will be expected. as SearchPage will have lot of product images.so maybe That jquery plugin is indirectly creating an thread in Application servers.

Comment: adding more worker threads to your pool seems the obvious solution. 1 second of googling suggests its "xr.image.background.workers"

Answer (score 0):

There is thread leakage in this class of flyingsaucer jar. I got answer for this problem on below URL.

https://technotailor.wordpress.com/2017/04/17/thread-leak-with-imageloadworker-in-flying-saucer-jar/